# How can we align the asp page in the following format

Tags: asp.net

My page contains images and labels which are bound to a datalist.
The label gets the text from a stored procedure. I need to align it in the following format.

**IMAGE** Label( The text starts right to the image and continues..

below the image when it is too lengthy..)

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlnews" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" 
                                                            onitemcommand="dlnews_ItemCommand">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
             <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                  <asp:Label ID="lbltitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Title")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td  style="width: 10%;"> 
                  <img id="imgn"  style="height: 70px; width: 70px" runat="server" src='xxx' />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:Label ID="lCont" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'> 
                  </asp:Label>
                </td>
        </tr>
          </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Now i've attached the code..

Many Thanks
ASr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<style>
div.img
{float:left;}
div.txt
{width:50px;}
</style>

<div style='width:100px;height:1000px;'>
<div class='img'>
<img src='test'/>
</div>
<div>
Text Text Text Text 
</div>
<div class='img'>
<img src='test'/>
</div>
<div>
Text 
</div>
<div class='img'>
<img src='test'/>
</div>
<div>
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
</div>
```

Comment: ya thanks.. But if i put a 'asp:Label' In the place of 'Text' it dint give me the expected result.. here the text displayed below the image (which i dint prefer)

Comment: Then use <div id="test" runat="server"><%# Eval("Description") %></div> instead. Unless there is a 'need' for you to use a label.

Answer (score 0):

look at the code below

```
<div>
<img src="sss" alt="aa" /><span style="word-wrap:break-word;"><asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" text="your text" /></span>

</div>
```

Comment: i have entered the answer but it is not displayed

Comment: after entering the code select it and click the "code sample" button above the editor.

Thanks,
ASr..